# Exception Updating All records in DB in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have this weird issue with Entity Framework with the code snippet below

```
var userWorkItems = (from uw in context.UserWorkItems
                     join u in context.DNN_Users on uw.UserID equals u.UserID
                     where u.Username.StartsWith(fromUserName)
                     select uw).ToList();

if (userWorkItems != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < userWorkItems.Count; i++)
    {
        userWorkItems[i].UserID = toUserID.Value;
    }

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The whole table gets updated with the `Userid` of the `fromUserName` when an exception occurs.

What kind of exception leads to this kind of weird behavior, though a try catch has been added now to the `context.SubmitChanges();`

Or are we making the wrong conclusion?

Comment: *an exception*. Please elaborate.

Comment: An exception is thrown on submitchanges() I presume and the whole record on the userworkitems table is updated. Sadly we cannot reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

Where does the exception occur and what is the exception? I believe your issue might be `fromUserName`. If it was an empty string, it would return every single `UserWorkItem`. If an error is thrown and you don't want it to do a partial save on the context, wrap it in a `TransactionScope` like so.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope()){
    //Do whatever
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to solve the problem yet, I am trying to find out what caused it. Was it the exception? If it is yes what kind of exception causes this kind of weird behavior with EF

Comment: Wrapping it in a transaction scope will help you reproduce the error without worrying about it changing all of the rows again. I have never heard of EF editing all of the rows in a table unless it was told to. Judging by your code, like I said, if fromUserName was an empty string, it would return every row.

Comment: Quiet interesting the user who wrote the code is just trimming the user input and not checking if the textbox actually contains any string, i just added the check in, never knew startswith returns all the rows if the parameter is an empty string thanks a lot

Comment: No Problem @kolexinfos